# Formatting Issues in SQL Developer 20.1

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer 20.2. I see some issues in the formatting.
Whenever I press ctrl+F7 to format a package, procedure declarations after multiline comments are getting indented by 4 spaces. Ideally, this should be indented only once. But everytime i press ctrl+F7, these get indented by 4 spaces. How do i get rid of this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Reported on our forums as well, smells like a bug https://community.oracle.com/thread/4336648?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Follow the link in my comments for the fix